# Convergence of a series implies convergence of another one

Tags: sequences-and-series

In one step of a proof I found the following:
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_j^2} < + \infty $$ implies that for all $k$ positive integers and $t>0$, also $a_j>0$ for all $j$
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty e^{-a_j t} a_j^k < +\infty$$

Not only I found that a bit counterintuitive, but I really can't find out why this is true in the general case. I tried with simple examples like $a_j = j$ and it works with the ratio test, but I can't find out how to do the general case (I suspect some kind of estimation is involved, maybe Taylor?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a_j>0$ for all $j$, (otherwise the series with the exponent diverges),
use the fact that for every integer $k>0$, $t>0$,  you can find a sufficiently large $M>0$ such that for all $x>M$ you have $e^{-xt}x^{k+2}<1$, whence for sufficiently large $j$ the general term of you second series is majorized by a convergent series.

Comment: $a_j > 0$ is a legitimate hypothesis in the context of the proof... gonna try that